# Nodejs and express error handling on backend and frontend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm currently working on a portal website with nodejs, express and angular. One issue I have come across is how error handling should be done. I have read through the express error handling guide also and have implemented their default error handling function. So, I can't seem to find the best practice for this situation.

For example, if I am trying to retrieve from a database and it cannot be found, the server would send a 404 and in https request would handle it there on the client end. The only problem is, is that it sends the error message and stack trace into the client's console. My method was, based on that error, I would handle it on the client end by displaying a message such as "Incorrect password" or "Cannot find this e-mail in the database. Would you like to sign up?".

Another example I have is when a user inputs his credit card information. On the client end, there is a http request for his billing information. If I receive a "404" for no billing information found, I would bring up a add billing form. If it is a "200", I would display that current billing information on that same page.

What would be the best practice to catching errors on the front end without sending errors to the user?

```
function getBillingInfo(){
    $http.get('test/api/billinginfo', {
        params: {
            token: store.get('token')
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        //Retrieve billing information
        $scope.billingInfo = response.data;

        //Display current billing information
        $scope.billingState = "display";
    }, function (response) {
        //Display add billing form
        $scope.billingState = "add";
        //Initialize form input
        $scope.billingAdd = {
            country:"US",
            month:"month",
            year:"year",
            state:"AL"
        };
    });
}
```